# Android app crashes unusually

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

App version: 1.0.24

Device: Huawei Ascend G510 (running Android 4.1.1)

The app will crash after using it for a minute or two, but it doesn't say `Unfortunately, X has stopped.` responding. It just closes and I see the home screen on my phone. It has happened since I updated to v1.0.24. This doesn't happen on my tablet (a Nexus 7). I tried getting a logcat of what happens when it crashes and this is what I see:

```
03-20 00:10:28.970 F/libc    (27575): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 27575 (exchange.marvin)
03-20 00:10:29.020 E/dalvikvm(27575): GC_CONCURRENT freed 700K, 16% free 13127K/15559K, paused 16ms+5ms, total 69ms
03-20 00:10:29.080 I/DEBUG   (  147): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-20 00:10:29.080 I/DEBUG   (  147): Build fingerprint: 'Huawei/G510-0100/hwG510-0100:4.1.1/HuaweiG510-0100/C02B171:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'
03-20 00:10:29.080 I/DEBUG   (  147): pid: 27575, tid: 27575, name: exchange.marvin  >>> com.stackexchange.marvin <<<
03-20 00:10:29.080 I/DEBUG   (  147): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000008
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     r0 52571180  r1 00000008  r2 00000018  r3 00000000
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     r4 00000000  r5 00000040  r6 00000038  r7 00000008
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     r8 00000001  r9 408e94f8  sl 00000010  fp 5166fe98
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     ip 514def3c  sp bee67cd0  lr 514d5687  pc 4025c45c  cpsr 20000010
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d0  3f8000003f800000  d1  3f80000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d2  000000003f800000  d3  000000003f800000
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d4  000001e0000001e4  d5  000000003f800000
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d6  bf8111113f137c1b  d7  3f8000003f800000
03-20 00:10:29.560 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d8  c0000000c0000000  d9  000001cf00000170
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d10 0000000000000356  d11 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d16 00000000000042d8  d17 0000000000000001
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 bf80000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d20 bf80888900000000  d21 000000003f12e2a0
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d22 3d0000003f800000  d23 000000003d000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d28 407e600000000000  d29 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     d30 bff8000003000000  d31 0000000000000000
03-20 00:10:29.570 I/DEBUG   (  147):     scr 28000013
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147): backtrace:
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #00  pc 0000e45c  /system/lib/libc.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #01  pc 00004683  /system/lib/libgsl.so (ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_write+114)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #02  pc 0005462d  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (rb_vbo_cache_vertex_attrib+364)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #03  pc 0002909d  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (cache_vertex_array+378)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #04  pc 0002bfff  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (qgl2DrvAPI_glDrawArraysInstancedXXX+214)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #05  pc 000244d5  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (glDrawArrays+12)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #06  pc 000151df  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #07  pc 00015291  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #08  pc 00015337  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #09  pc 0000f9c5  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #10  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #11  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #12  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #13  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #14  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #15  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #16  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #17  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #18  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #19  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #20  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #21  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #22  pc 0000fbad  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #23  pc 0005b713  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #24  pc 0001f470  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #25  pc 0004e1b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #26  pc 00028920  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #27  pc 0002d0e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #28  pc 0005faeb  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+374)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #29  pc 00066ba5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #30  pc 00028920  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #31  pc 0002d0e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147): stack:
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67c90  5203a200  
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67c94  515e7c79  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (glUniformMatrix4fv+12)
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67c98  516e47f0  
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67c9c  4090e947  /system/lib/libhwui.so
03-20 00:10:29.590 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ca0  40011112  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ca4  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ca8  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cac  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cb0  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cb4  c03d4d56  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cb8  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cbc  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cc0  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cc4  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cc8  df0027ad  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ccc  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #00  bee67cd0  52571180  /dev/kgsl-3d0
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cd4  514d5687  /system/lib/libgsl.so (ioctl_kgsl_sharedmem_write+118)
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #01  bee67cd8  51458080  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cdc  516889a8  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ce0  00000038  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ce4  51688988  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67ce8  5345a20c  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cec  516889a8  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cf0  51688988  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cf4  5345a20c  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cf8  516889a8  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67cfc  51617631  /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so (rb_vbo_cache_vertex_attrib+368)
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):     #02  bee67d00  40052078  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d04  516e4430  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d08  516d9500  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d0c  bee67d88  [stack]
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d10  00000014  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d14  00000001  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d18  51458080  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d1c  00000001  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d20  00000004  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d24  00000008  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d28  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d2c  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d30  00000000  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d34  400528e0  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d38  5345a20c  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          bee67d3c  40052078  
03-20 00:10:29.600 I/DEBUG   (  147):          ........  ........
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): memory near r0:
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     52571160 00000000 3f800000 00000000 3f800000  .......?.......?
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     52571170 3f800000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  ...?...?........
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     52571180 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     52571190 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     525711a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): memory near r9:
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     408e94d8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     408e94e8 00000000 00000000 4edcd094 000000cb  ...........N....
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     408e94f8 401d4998 00000038 51688928 00000008  .I.@8...(.hQ....
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     408e9508 00000038 00000000 00000000 00000000  8...............
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     408e9518 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): memory near fp:
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     5166fe78 516461d1 516461e9 5164408d 516440a5  .adQ.adQ.@dQ.@dQ
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     5166fe88 516440af 516440b7 516440c1 4026069c  .@dQ.@dQ.@dQ..&@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     5166fe98 00000000 00000000 00000000 514d5a05  .............ZMQ
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     5166fea8 514d5a09 40137f25 40278945 4025c3a0  .ZMQ%..@E.'@..%@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     5166feb8 4026a7ad 40137fb9 40137e65 514d4a51  ..&@...@e~.@QJMQ
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): memory near ip:
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514def1c 4025aca8 40267ab3 40267b0d 40265165  ..%@.z&@.{&@eQ&@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514def2c 4026518d 40265179 402651a1 402651b5  .Q&@yQ&@.Q&@.Q&@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514def3c 4025c3a0 4025bf40 40270dbd 40270d79  ..%@@.%@..'@y.'@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514def4c 4025c760 40287e07 4026531c 40270f4f  `.%@.~(@.S&@O.'@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514def5c 4026d531 40270249 40270f15 4026cfcd  1.&@I.'@..'@..&@
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147): memory near sp:
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     bee67cb0 00000000 c03d4d56 00000000 00000000  ....VM=.........
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     bee67cc0 00000000 00000000 df0027ad 00000000  .........'......
03-20 00:10:29.620 I/DEBUG   (  147):     bee67cd0 52571180 514d5687 51458080 516889a8  ..WR.VMQ..EQ..hQ
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     bee67ce0 00000038 51688988 5345a20c 516889a8  8.....hQ..ES..hQ
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     bee67cf0 51688988 5345a20c 516889a8 51617631  ..hQ..ES..hQ1vaQ
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147): code around pc:
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     4025c43c f400022d f400422d f440022d f440422d  -...-B..-.@.-B@.
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     4025c44c 2afffff1 e2822080 e2522020 3a000003  ...*. ..  R....:
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     4025c45c f421020d e2522020 f400022d 2afffffb  ..!.  R.-......*
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     4025c46c e2822020 e3120010 0a000001 f4210a0d    ............!.
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     4025c47c f4000a2d e1b0ce82 3a000001 f421070d  -..........:..!.
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147): 
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147): code around lr:
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514d5664 f2404478 9001434a 95042002 fc6cf000  xD@.JC... ....l.
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514d5674 30fff04f 6800e006 46111840 f000461a  O..0...h@..F.F..
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514d5684 4620f9b9 bd70b006 00007dd5 00005fda  .. F..p..}..._..
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514d5694 000061e3 00005fb6 00007da7 000061e9  .a..._...}...a..
03-20 00:10:29.630 I/DEBUG   (  147):     514d56a4 4604b530 4608b087 4918b97c 48184622  0..F...F|..I"F.H
```

Comment: Segfault strikes again! It's probably a bad dereference somewhere, because it's trying to access memory location `8`. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the trace it's the result of your phone running out of memory. Since we don't do any native code in our app, but do heavily use `WebView`s, I'm assuming this is causing the low RAM of your device (512MB) to max out. I don't really know what we can do about this though, since our app definitely needs `WebView`s to work, and it works fine on my low-end test phone (4.0.4 / 512MB).

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks anyway

Comment: Can you point the clue which figure out it is "out of memory" cause the Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008?